# What is Perl's equivalent to awk's /text/,/END/?

Tags: perl, awk

I am looking to replace a nasty shell script that uses awk to trim down some HTML. The problem is I cannot find anything in Perl that does the aforementioned function

```
awk '/<TABLE\ WIDTH\=\"100\%\" BORDER\=1\ CELLSPACING\=0><TR\ class\=\"tabhead\"><TH>State<\/TH>/,/END/'
```

How can I do this in Perl?

the expected output would be

```
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0><TR class="tabhead"><TH>State</TH>
```

The Perl flipflop operator gives me WAY more. (Everything between the asterisks is junk)

```
*<h2>Browse Monitors (1 out of 497)</h2><br><font size="-1" style="font-weight:normal"> Use the <A HREF=/SiteScope/cgi/go.exe/SiteScope?page=monitorSummary&account=login15 >Monitor Description Report</a> to view current monitor configuration settings.</font>*<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0><TR class="tabhead"><TH>State</TH>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
perl -ne 'print if /text/ .. /END/'
```

`expr1 .. expr2` will be false until it encounters a line where `expr1` is true.
Then it will be true until it encounters a line where `expr2` is true.

---

**Update:** if you need to trim the non-matching text from the front of the first matching line, this will work

```
perl -ne 'print if s/.*TEXT/TEXT/ .. s/END.*/END/`
```

or

```
perl -ne 'print if s/.*(TEXT)/$1/ .. s/(END).*/$1/'
```

if TEXT is a long string that you only want to type once. The change will edit the line while it does the pattern match.

Comment: it is called "flip-flop" operator.

Comment: appears the flipflop doest trim the way I figured it would. I need to trim all the data infront of it, it appears the flip-flop only looks to see the line "contains" it where the awk actually cuts it down to just the looked for text.

Comment: Again mobrule you came through with the win... now I need to sit down and figure out what you did ;)

Comment: With this specific example (text containing forward slashes) it's probably worth mentioning that you can choose your own delimiter for `s` and `m`: `print if m{<TH>State</TH>} .. m{END} # no need to escape the slash`. (`m` here being what's implied when you write `/regex/` - it's the same as `m/regex/`). A lot of the backslashed text doesn't need to be backslashed, so given custom delimiters you can entirely get rid of all the backslashes here.

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner (slightly changed since first post):

```
perl -n -e '$started = 1 if /<TABLE\ WIDTH\=\"100\%\" BORDER\=1\ CELLSPACING\=0><TR\ class\=\"tabhead\"><TH>State<\/TH>/; next unless $started; print; last if /END/;'
```

From the perlrun man page:

> ```
>    -n   causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program,
> ```
>
> which makes it iterate over filename
>   arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:
>
> ```
>           LINE:
>             while (<>) {
>                 ...             # your program goes here
>             }
> ```

And then the core of the body is to wait for the start, then print every line until the end.