# Remove lines within delimiters, except those matching a regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I want to remove all text between two strings except lines that begin with certain strings. Using the following example, I want to get rid of the text between the strings `BEGIN` and `END` that is in the lines that do not begin with `BREAK1` or `BREAK2`:

```
keep keep keep
BEGIN
remove remove remove
remove remove remove
BREAK1 keep keep keep
remove remove remove
BREAK2 keep keep keep
remove remove remove
END
keep keep keep
```

Does anybody know how I can do that with regexes?

Comment: Regexps are not magic bullets. In this case you'd probably be better off doing it in a more straightforward programmatical fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
s/(?:^BEGIN\R|\G(?<!\A)(?:(?:BREAK1|BREAK2).*\R|END(?=\R|$)))\K|\G(?<!\A).*\R//gm
```

The idea is to match first all that must be preserved and to reset it from the match result with `\K`. The `\G` anchor is used to ensure that the different part of the match are contiguous. However, the current pattern doesn't check the presence of tag "END". If it is not present the replacement continue to the end of the string (the same behaviour than an html tag). To avoid this behaviour you can add a lookahead at the end: `(?=(?s).*?\REND(?:\R|$))`

pattern details:

```
(?:                       # non capturing group for all that must be preserved
    ^BEGIN\R              # the word "BEGIN" at the start of a line, followed
                          # by a newline
  |                       # OR
    \G                    # contiguous to a precedent match or at the start of
                          # the string
    (?<!\A)               # lookbehind: not preceded by the start of the string
    (?:                   # non capturing group: all that must be contiguous
        (?:BREAK1|BREAK2) # one of this two words
        .*\R              # all until the newline (included)
      |                   # OR
        END               # 
        (?=\R|$)          # lookahead to check if END is followed by a newline
                          # or the end of the string. Since it is a zero-width 
                          # assertion and doesn't match anything, it is used to
                          # contiguous matches.
    )                     # close the 2nd non capturing group
)                         # close the 1st non capturing group
\K                        # reset the 1st non capturing group from match result
|                         # OR
\G(?<!\A).*\R             # all that is contiguous to a precedent match until
                          # the newline (included)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
perl -ne 'print if !(/^BEGIN/ .. /^END/) or /^BREAK/' file
```

output

```
keep keep keep
BREAK1 keep keep keep
BREAK2 keep keep keep
keep keep keep
```

`..` in scalar context is perl [flip-flop opeartor](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators), and `/^BEGIN/ .. /^END/` will evaluate to `true` for all lines between `BEGIN` and `END` inclusive.

Comment: +1 elegant :) I was trying to come up with an awk version of this, but I bet I couldn't do it as elegantly at all...

Comment: @OlivierDulac I'm not familiar with awk, but perhaps this can be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526161/what-is-perls-equivalent-to-awks-text-end

Comment: I love it when a perl script is easier to read than an awk one! (and it should almost always be the case, given the power of perl... unfortunately many go for the "golfscripted" version instead of the readable (and easier to mange) ones). Thanks for keeping it nice and sane :)

Comment: @OlivierDulac I know what you mean and I'm also in favor of readability :)

Comment: You should explain how this works. The `..` operator is a bit uncommon for this kind of usage. ;)

Comment: +1 for a more legible solution (although I always enjoy Casimir's style too) :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could read or split it into @lines, and then loop through each line, keeping track of your state (inside or outside of a BEGIN..END block). If outside, keep and pass on the line. If inside, discard if `$line =~ m/^BREAK\d+\s*(.*)$/` returns FALSE, else $1 contains the keep text. I'll leave it as an exercise to the student to determine if you're in a BEGIN block.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a perl question, but I can't resist to post a `sed(1)` solution:

```
sed '/^BEGIN/,/^END/ { /^BREAK[12]/!d }'
```

Answer (score -1):

On a linux machine, You can run egrep command

```
egrep -v ^BREAK
```